# makeKeyAndOrderFront only does the latter

Tags: cocoa, nswindow

I am trying to open one window from another using makeKeyAndOrderFront.  The new window appears, but does not receive focus.

The code for the main window is:

```
#import "SecondWindowController.h"
@implementation FirstWindowController
-(IBAction)showSecondWindow:(id)sender
{
  if (!secondWindowController)
    secondWindowController = [[SecondWindowController alloc] init];
  [[secondWindowController window] makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
}
```

SecondWindowController is a NSWindowController, as follows:

```
@implementation SecondWindowController
-(id)init
{
  if (![super initWithWindowNibName:@"SecondWindow"])
    return nil;
  return self;
}
```

I've also tried putting `[secondWindowController showWindow:self]` before the `makeKeyAndOrderFront` but it doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you make sure the window outlet for SecondWindowController is hooked up to the window in your NIB? The window could be displayed just by loading the NIB, even if the outlet is not hooked up.

Comment: Yeah, you got it.  I had set the delegate to the File's Owner object, but hadn't set the window the other way.  Is this correct to change the class of File's Owner to SecondWindowController?

Comment: Yes, set the class of File's Owner to SecondWindowController.

Answer (score 6):

Are you using a borderless window? If so you need to override canBecomeKeyWindow and return YES

Comment: I'm not sure what a borderless window is, so I haven't intentionally created one.  However, canBecomeKeyWindow does return NO.  To override this, do I need to subclass NSWindow for that instance?

Comment: Yea, you have to override the NSWindow class.

Comment: Actually, now I think that Doug Richardson is right. Your [secondWindowController window] is probably nil!!!!!

Comment: A borderless window is an NSWindow with NSWindow.styleMask = NSWindow.StyleMask.borderless. I don't know the right syntax for Objective-C.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if (!secondWindowController)
    secondWindowController = [[SecondWindowController alloc] init];    
NSApplication *thisApp = [NSApplication sharedApplication];
[thisApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
[[secondWindowController window] makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
```

Comment: This makes no difference, still appears in front, but without focus.

Comment: Oh, no focus? How about [window makeFirstResponder:nil]?